# Detecting last modified date and time of a CodeClass object in a T4 template

Tags: silverlight, t4, codedom

In my Silverlight test project I have created a T4 template, which detects all the CodeClass objects in the project, which derive from System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, groups them according to their namespaces, and creates a navigation bar containing links to all user controls in the project. Now I'd like to somehow outline the UserControl on which I am currently working, so is it possible to detect the last modified DateTime of a CodeClass object in a T4 template?